# What difference does it make if you test a model on a test set that includes the outcome?

Tags: r, machine-learning

What difference does it make if you test a model on a testing set that already includes the outcome? Theoretically this would provide additional information to the model, but when I run an example, the results are the same. I'll use an SVM as an example below.

Say you train an svm on a portion of iris data.

```
set.seed(123)
split = sample.split(iris$Species, SplitRatio = 0.75)
training_set = subset(iris, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(iris, split == FALSE)
```

create model

```
 classifier = svm(formula = Species ~ .,
                 data = training_set,
                 type = 'C-classification',
                 kernel = 'radial')
```

Now we're going to have two predictions. On the testing set without the outcome available to the model (the correct way) and the testing set with the outcome available. 
Version 1:

```
    #create prediction WITHOUT outcome i.e. test_set[-5]
    y_pred <- predict(classifier, newdata = test_set[-5])
    table( y_pred, test_set[, 5])
       y_pred       setosa versicolor virginica
        setosa         12          0         0
        versicolor      0         12         1
        virginica       0          0        11
```

Version 2:

```
    #create prediction WITH outcome i.e. the entire test set
    y_pred <- predict(classifier, newdata = test_set)
    table( y_pred, test_set[, 5])
      y_pred       setosa versicolor virginica
       setosa         12          0         0
       versicolor      0         12         1
       virginica       0          0        11
```

Both versions 1 and 2 show identical results. Why is that? Is the model just ignoring the outcome on its own, or are the rest of the features good enough to give a prediction anyways?

Comment: When predicting, only the columns you used as predictor are included. The response column is ignored as well as any other columns that weren't included in the model. I'm not sure what else you were expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, your two code snippets are in fact equivalent; in the 2nd snippet:

```
y_pred <- predict(classifier, newdata = test_set)
```

the 5th column `test_set[5]` containing the outcomes, under the hood, is in fact **removed** from the data fed to the model and it is not used for producing the actual predictions.

But this is an interesting example to demonstrate how a language feature meant for convenience can potentially lead new users to such confusion: actually here, the only reason that your 2nd snippet works at all without throwing an error is due to the *formula interface* (a rather distinctive characteristic of R) used in model fitting.

To see how the situation could be easily different, let's make some (seemingly unimportant and trivial) changes; let's separe features from labels manually, and use instead the alternative *data interface* for fitting the model:

```
X = training_set[,1:4]
y = training_set[5]

classifier = svm(X, y,
                 type = 'C-classification',
                 kernel = 'radial')
```

This will lead the 2nd snippet to fail (`test_set` now, in contrast to `X` used for training, contains the labels too, i.e. one more column), simply because it gets more input features (5) than it expects (4):

```
pred = predict(classifier, test_set)

Error in scale.default(newdata[, object$scaled, drop = FALSE], center = object$x.scale$"scaled:center",  : 
  length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'
Calls: predict -> predict.svm -> scale -> scale.default
Execution halted
```

In this case, it is our responsibility to prepare the data so that they contain the exact same features used for training - no less, but also no more:

```
pred = predict(classifier, test_set[,1:4]) # works OK
```

but it arguably prevents also potential confusions such the ones you have expressed here...

---

Looking further than R, this second situation (i.e. the data interface instead if the formula one) is rather the rule than the exception. Here is the case with Python and sciki-learn; without providing the full example for brevity (leave a comment if you wish to see it in full), with `X` and `y` the iris features and labels respectively, we fit a classifier as

```
clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X,y)
```

but if we merge `X` and `y` into a single variable `X_plus` and we try to predict with it, we get an expected error for excessive columns:

```
clf.predict(X_plus)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-21-b7d5b72a1945> in <module>()
----> 1 clf.predict(X_plus)


/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py in decision_function(self, X)
    271         if X.shape[1] != n_features:
    272             raise ValueError("X has %d features per sample; expecting %d"
--> 273                              % (X.shape[1], n_features))
    274 
    275         scores = safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,

ValueError: X has 5 features per sample; expecting 4
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly the explanation I needed! I didn't understand the nuances of the formula, but your example describes it perfectly!

Comment: @PleaseHelp Cool. It's just you were kinda late to respond and I worried that I may have written all this for nothing :)

Comment: My apologies! I'm new to SO and didn't expect a response quite so fast!